# Deciding between MDR solutions offering endpoint agents with or without an additional network appliance?

Tags: network, ids, detection

There are a number of different **Managed Security Service Providers** (MSSPs) offering managed detection and response services. They tend to use what is called an **endpoint agent**, while only some use a **network appliance** in addition.

We have a small office network with a couple dozen endpoints. The MSSPs we are looking at offer both endpoint agents providing **Endpoint Detection and Response** (EDR) with an optional network appliance acting as a **Network Intrusion Detection System**, or NIDS, attached to the firewall.

It has been recommended that we purchase both the endpoint agents and the network applicance, but the latter comes at a significant additional cost.

How do we figure out whether the network appliance is worth it or not?

Comment: I've suggested some edits for the question. I think it may ultimately be hard to provide a specific answer to whether it is "worth it" or not, without knowing more about your requirements. You have mentioned cost, but what other variables are you weighing in the decision process?

Comment: You can run a NIDS with SecurityOnion or OwlH. You can run an EDR with Velocidex or LimaCharlie.io -- Just run your own. You don't need anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Network appliance additions tend to have benefits when your network security controls are insufficient.

If your network is managed (to a sufficient level), events are pulled into a SIEM, network segmentation is inplace and access control is based on a secure mechanism (e.g certificates and without you get blackholed) network level still has some benefits but not so much.

If your security controls at network level are to your own taste not sufficient a network appliance can assist you in getting to start on the controls I mentioned.

Personally i'd go with endpoint based and kick anything which doesn't have the required properties off of my network (automatically)